# PostgreSQL:string concatanation in select query

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given below is my *select query*

```
select 
     case
      when mobile||', '||phoneoff  <>', ' then mobile||', '||phoneoff 
      when phoneoff='' and mobile<>''  then mobile 
      when phoneoff<>'' and mobile='' then phoneoff 
     else 'NIL' 
     end as "Concat_result",phoneoff,mobile
from gtab12
```

*Result*

```
      Concat_result|  phoneoff  | mobile
-------------------+------------+----------  
9544070335, 2812111|2812111     |9544070335
                NIL|            |
     , 0479-2436762|0479-2436762|
       9495758057, |            |9495758057
```

---

what I'm trying to achieve is, 
if both `phoneoff` and `mobile` have value then it should concatenate with a `,` see `Concat_result` *col* in the first *row* in the *result*

If `phoneoff` and `mobile` are `= ''` then `Concat_result` should print `NIL`

If `phoneoff<>''` and  `mobile=''` then `Concat_result` should print `phoneoff` only (see *row* 3 in my result its showing `phoneoff` along with `,`) and same for `mobile<>''`

---

*Expecting Result*

```
      Concat_result|  phoneoff  | mobile
-------------------+------------+----------  
9544070335, 2812111|2812111     |9544070335
                NIL|            |
      0479-2436762 |0479-2436762|           
       9495758057  |            |9495758057
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple one-liner, which uses [`NULLIF()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html) & [`COALESCE()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html) (therefore can handle `NULL` values too, not just empty strings):

```
select coalesce(nullif(concat_ws(', ', nullif(phoneoff, ''), nullif(mobile, '')), ''), 'NIL') "Concat_result", phoneoff, mobile
from gtab12
```

Answer (score 2):

Postgres has `concat_ws`, which can help:

```
select concat_ws(', ', phoneoff, mobile) as Concat_result, phoneoff, mobile
from gtab12 ;
```

This doesn't quite do what you want, because you care about special values and `'NIL'`.  So, let's put that logic in:

```
select (case when phoneoff = '' and mobile = '' then 'NIL'
             else concat_ws(', ',
                            (case when phoneoff <> '' then phoneoff end),
                            (case when mobile <> '' then mobile end)
                           )
        end) as Concat_result, phoneoff, mobile
from gtab12 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
 case
    when (mobile<>'' and phoneoff<>'') then mobile||', '||phoneoff 
    when phoneoff='' and mobile<>''  then mobile 
    when phoneoff<>'' and mobile='' then phoneoff 
    else 'NIL' 
 end as "Concat_result",phoneoff,mobile
from gtab12
```